# How to determine the network bandwidth usage for a server call?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I would like to determine the network bandwidth usage when I make a call like below.

https://example.com/logEvent?clientId=samsung+sm-t320&sessionId=2AA8A8E2050120C6-60000137C0001656&clientOs=4.4.2&clientVersion=33.0.0&appId=com.abc.app&accountId=f5370a7b-6356-4a0b-b139-9b42ad23e09c&issueId=1&code=ArticleDownloadStarted

I am open to using some developer tools available as an extension to the browser or other standalone tools or a way of doing this programmatically in Java.

---

Background: I am being told that I should be very careful about number of server calls I make to our internal logging server from a mobile device, as it can impact data the end user. I understand that I should only log what's needed, but I want to analysis the impact of making these calls to understand the cost of each calls to better understand the trade-off between network bandwidth usage and having the information needed for solving production issues quickly.

Thanks!

Comment: Ever thought of decreasing the number of roundtrips to the server by for example collecting events to be logged for a certain amount of time (preferably seconds) and then sending them in bulk to the server with one POST ? The amount of bytes will be the same but it is always better to send a big chunk of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of tools you can use, to a certain degree depending on which amount of data you expect:

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) or any similar "proxy", your favorite browsers F12 tool, ...

Wireshark is rather complex but it has nice statistics functions or plugins.